# how to prevent validation when view and viewModel are initialized and displayed for the first time?

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I am using Prism+MVVM+C#+WPF for a LoB application.
I've created a ViewModelBase class, which is inherited by all my viewModels.
This base class implements:

- IViewModel (one of my base interfaces)
- IDataErrorInfo (in order to allow ViewModel validation)

It follows my IDataErrorInfo implementation:

```
#region IDataErrorInfo members

    public string this[string propertyName]
    {
        get { return this.Validate(propertyName); }
    }

    public string Error { get; private set; }

    #endregion

    protected string Validate(string propertyName)
    {
        this.Error = null;

        PropertyInfo property = this.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
        if (property == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("propertyName");

        foreach (ValidationAttribute attribute in property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ValidationAttribute), true))
        {
            try
            {
                object currentValue = property.GetValue(this, null);
                attribute.Validate(currentValue, propertyName);
            }
            catch (ValidationException ex)
            {
                string errorMessage = (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(attribute.ErrorMessage) ? attribute.ErrorMessage: ex.Message);

                if (this.Error == null)
                    this.Error = errorMessage;
                else
                    this.Error += string.Format("\r\n{0}", errorMessage);
            }
        }

        return this.Error;
    }
```

In a given point of the application, I am building and associating View and ViewModel in this way:

```
IViewModel viewModel = this.ServiceLocator.GetInstance(typeof(IMyViewModel)) as IMyViewModel;
IView view = this.ServiceLocator.GetInstance(type) as IMyView;

view.ViewModel = viewModel;
this.GlobalRegionManager.Regions[RegionNames.InnerRegion].Add(view);
```

The problem is occurs when the view starts to read up the viewModel properties. The "this[string propertyName]" is invoked and the validation function gets executed...

In the views, the binding of the properties that need to be validated is defined as:

```
Text="{Binding SourceFileName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
```

Could you advice on how to prevent the initial validation?

Thanks in advance,
Gianluca

Comment: Why exactly is it a problem that the validation is executed?

Comment: @stijn: initially the view fields are empty. no validation error should appear at the very beginning. I would expect the system to signal invalid values when I start to write in a field... maybe I could achieve this result by using UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, but it would not be exactly what I neeed...

Comment: Can you modify your `validation` function to treat `null` as valid and then check any non-nullable properties before `submit` (for example)

Comment: @Bolu: I use the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations validation attributes.. I should define my own attrs, which is something that I would not like to do in order to remain "standard". Also, it would  be a problem when using [Required(AllowEmptyStrings=false)] on a String property for example...

Comment: if you *really* want to get into this, you have to add extra logic that for each property checks if the user already entered at least one character. If not, validation result is true, else yuo validate the input. However you have a contradiction here: fields cannot be empty anyway, so isn't it logical to display them as invalid?